# Bitnami Wordpress WPMU Stack Primary domain

Tags: amazon-ec2, hosting, wordpress, bitnami

First time bitnami user here. I'm having some problems after installing this bitnami ami (ami-b7a29cc3) which is Wordpress MU.

I have a site residing [here](http://ec2-176-34-127-170.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/)  on amazon EC2 obviously.

I'm struggling with adding my domain to it rather than the default DNS of the EC2.

The domain I've pointed at it is topmmorpg100.com.

Just not having a lot of luck with it. Seems to be a routing issue of some description as the domain is pointing to the EC2 just fine.

```
MacBook-Pro:$ ping topmmorpg100.com PING topmmorpg100.com (176.34.127.170): 56 data bytes
```

Not sure of the answer, I have followed [this guide](http://wiki.bitnami.org/Applications/BitNami_Wordpress_Stack#How_to_change_the_default_URL.3f) and updated the URLs in the database and made the changes this document suggest I need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `tracert` reveals that the problem is somewhere in your Amazon EC2 config:

```
tracert topmmorpg100.com

Tracing route to topmmorpg100.com [176.34.127.170]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

[cut]
  8     7 ms     7 ms     7 ms  TenGigabitEthernet-1-2.br0.ams-nik.concepts-ict.
net [213.197.18.10]
  9     7 ms     7 ms     7 ms  amsix01-ams1.amazon.com [195.69.146.100]
 10    23 ms    22 ms     *     178.236.3.39
 11    23 ms    22 ms    22 ms  178.236.3.124
 12    23 ms    23 ms    22 ms  178.236.0.97
 13    24 ms    22 ms    22 ms  178.236.0.58
 14    24 ms    22 ms    20 ms  ec2-79-125-0-4.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com [
79.125.0.4]
 15     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 16     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

Are you sure you've either set up an A record in your DNS server pointing to the Amazon Elastic IP associated with the EC2 instance you've set up, or to your Elastic LoadBalancer (ELB)?

You can also try using a CNAME and pointing it to `ec2-176-34-127-170.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com` but this is strongly dispreferred, because this address **will** change when you switch instances, etc. Much better to use an Elastic IP, or an ELB if your traffic requires load-balancing.

Comment: I have pointed the A record at the Elastic IP address given to me, perhaps I should update it to the full DNS path - ec2-176-34-127-170.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com ?

Comment: No, that can't work: A records only work for 32-bit IPv4 addresses. Are you sure that is the correct Elastic IP address, and that it is bound to the correct instance? If you've switched instances since acquiring that Elastic IP, you'll have to reassign it; it'll be waiting for you in the AWS web console under Network & security on the EC2 tab.

Comment: Yup positive Address: 176.34.127.170
Instance ID: i-6467462d (topmmorp-WP-multi)
Scope: standard
Public DNS: ec2-176-34-127-170.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com

Comment: Hmm, that's all configured correctly. Here's the real problem: if you go to `176.34.127.170` or `http://topmmorpg100.com/`, the page `wp-signup.php` keeps redirecting you to...itself! Just open up Google Chrome, hit F12 (for Developer Tools), click `Network` and `Preserve logs upon navigation` (left of the button that says `All`), then point your browser to either `176.34.127.170` or `http://topmmorpg100.com/`. You'll have to look in that particular PHP file for the problem. I'd imagine it's to do with a location header it sends out?

Comment: Yeah I think your right, didn't think it was a problem with the domain resolving or not. I think unless you know about Wordpress MU problems it won't be an easy answer. I'd imagine the problem will be to do with the routing.

Comment: Could well be this if ( !is_main_site() ) {
 wp_redirect( network_home_url( 'wp-signup.php' ) );
 die();
}

Comment: I seem to have fixed it, to some degree.

Comment: No, just seemed that way because of the `tracert` I ran. But you're right, all that's configured correctly. http://wordpress.org/support/topic/accidently-made-my-site-redirect-onto-itself-under-settings-help seems to suggest you may need to change the site URL in the table `wp_options` using something like phpMyAdmin or the command-line MySQL tool...but I've never used WP much, so at this point I'll just zip it rather than confuse you more ;)

edit: yes, works for me too, now - what was the problem?

Comment: The problem was I need to both edit the options in the wp_options table and also edit the main url in the wp_blogs table, only added when multisite is enabled. And also completely missing from bitnami's change of domain guide. Useful :) it all appears to be running okay now.